# Check if an specific file available or not in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
File_Name = "Invoice_Dmart"
Folder-Name = "c:\Documents\Scripts\Bills"
```

How to check if the specific filename exist in the "Folder-Name" with any extension, If Yes Get the full path in a variable.

Code i have been using:

```
import os.path
if not os.path.Folder-Name(File_Name):
      print("The File s% it's not created "%File_Name)
      os.touch(File_Name)
      print("The file s% has been Created ..."%File_Name)
```

Please Suggest the best possible way to solve it.

Comment: When you say "with any extension", do mean that the file may be "Invoice_Dmart.txt" or "Invoice_Dmart.csv" or "Invoice_Dmart.pdf" etc?

Comment: By the way, `Folder-Name` is an invalid variable name in Python. So your example code (that you have apparently been using?) doesn't work. `os.path.some_folder_name(File_Name)` will also not work: it is incorrect usage of `os.path`.

Answer (score 2):

Before, you should fix the syntax of the variable `Folder-Name` to `Folder_Name`.

I guess you can solve the problem by simply adding the two strings through a slash, and using the function [os.path.exists()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-file-or-directory-exists/#:%7E:text=isfile()%20Method%20to%20check,existing%20regular%20file%20or%20not.) like:

```
import os.path

File_Name = "Invoice_Dmart"
Folder_Name = "c:\Documents\Scripts\Bills"

path = os.path.join(Folder_Name, File_Name)
     
exist = os.path.exists(path)
print(exist)
```

Using [os.path.join()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/) aswell to add up the strings, it automatically puts a slash in between.

It worked for me, hope it also does for you.

Comment: `"\"` is a syntax error. Better to use `os.path.join()`.

Comment: @9769953 That must be right, I'll edit it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pathlib.Path` here. It provides convenient apis to iterate over the directories(`.iterdir()`) and also to get the filename without extension(`.stem`). So you can do somewhat like this.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> [str(child) for child in Path(your_folder_name).iterdir() if child.stem == your_file_name]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we use os.path.isFile(file_name) instead of using loop. And How to get the full path of the file if Filename is found in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below

```
import os

file_name = "Invoice_Dmart"
folder_name = "c:\Documents\Scripts\Bills"

# os.path.splitext() split filename and ext
# os.listdir() list all files in the given dir
filenames_wo_ext = [os.path.splitext(elem)[0] for elem in os.listdir(folder_name)]
if file_name not in filenames_wo_ext:
    print("The File %s it's not created "% file_name)
    with open(file_name, 'w'):
        print("The file %s has been Created ..."% file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Library `pathlib` is more powerfull than `os`. `os` treats paths like string and `pathlib` treats them as pathways (based on Operating System you are using).

```
from pathlib import Path

data_path = PurePath(f'C:\YourPath\{even_with_variables}\file.txt')
    
    if not Path(data_path).exists():
        return None
    else:
        return True
```